# Replace auto keyword with deduced type (clang or VS2010)

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, auto

Has anyone written a script, plugin, or executable that replaces each instance of 'auto' with the compiler-deduced type?  I need to port some C++11 code that uses auto all over the place.

Clang is my first candidate.  Has anyone modified it to do something like this?

An alternative is to parse the errors from a compiler as the expected type might be in the error output.  I could `-Dauto=int` and possibly get back `"could not convert std::vector<int>::iterator to 'int'"`

Comment: Not likely. We tend to port software to C++11, not from C++11.

Comment: It's not even possible -- not within templates where the type depends on template parameters.

Comment: But as far as I know, VisualStudio is smart enough to tell you the type if you hover over the variable with your mouse -- unless it depends on template parameters of course.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible in the general case.  Consider:

```
template <typename T> void foo(T & t)
{
    auto it = t.find(42);
    ...
}
...
std::map<int, int> m;
std::set<int> s;
...
foo(m);
foo(s);
```

Admittedly a pointless example, but it shows that there's no way to know what to replace auto with, when dependent on a template argument.  `std::map` and `std::set`, incidentally, contain typedefs of the same name (`iterator`) that represent the type of the respective iterator, so `typename T::iterator it` would work here, but you can instantiate `foo` for a `T` that does not have such a typedef.

The numerous typedefs in the standard library classes were added exactly to allow such templates to be written before `auto` was invented/re-purposed, and you can do the same thing to deal with a compiler that doesn't have `auto`.  But it's not something you can automate, at least not without an effort comparable to adding support for `auto` to a compiler...

Even when `auto` is not dependent on a template type, it is a difficult problem to replace it with something that makes sense to the user and is portable.  Take:

```
std::map<int, int> m;
auto it = m.find(42);
```

The reasonable replacement for `auto` is `std::map<int, int>::iterator`, but if you use `-Dauto=int` and look at the compiler error messages, you'd replace it with something like `std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int, int> >`.  That's implementation detail of the standard library, hard to read and obviously not portable -- you don't want *that* in your code.

In your very example, my compiler (GCC 4.4.6) says:

> error: cannot convert `__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<int*, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >` to `int` in initialization

Comment: > at least not without an effort comparable to adding support for `auto` to a compiler—Many features provided by IDEs / language servers today are about as hard as adding them to a compiler, so this doesn't seem like a compelling reason anymore.