# Automatically rewrite c++11 auto keyword into derived types

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Maybe a strange question, but is there any software available which, given a bunch of c++11 code, derives all types of the auto-typed variables and rewrites the code with those derived types? And also for initializer lists?

The reasoning is that we would like to provide a backwards compatible version of our code (non C++11), mainly for portability with osx. Auto-typing and initializer lists are the features we use most as they make the code a lot more readable, but removing them by hand is a no-go.
As this is in fact what the compiler does with auto-typed variables, it does not seem too far-fetched?

Comment: Can you elaborate @sehe? Does clang do something in that fashion? FYI, clang 3.0 does not support enough features in C++11 to compile our code.

Comment: @BroesDeCat: He was suggesting that you use Clang's compiler library to compile your code, and then write it back out, with the `auto`'s all converted to their deduced types.

Comment: Note: It's called *deduced*, the type is deduced from the initializer.

Comment: I like the proposed solutions, but it still does not solve the whole problem and we currently also do not use boost. No other solutions?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935590/replace-auto-keyword-with-deduced-type-clang-or-vs2010?rq=1 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508512/automate-backporting-c11-auto-declarations?lq=1 The conclusion is that it's impossible for at least some uses of auto.

Answer (score 3):

Look at BOOST_AUTO and/or BOOST_TYPEOF

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/typeof/refe.html#typeof.typo

You could substitute

```
 auto x = foo();
```

with

```
 BOOS_AUTO(x, foo());
```

If you wanted to 'manage' a decltype you'd have to resort to BOOST_TYPEOF. Note that both macros have some variants that you will want to read more about

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Boost, then you might look at [boost::typeof](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/typeof.html). It won't do exactly what `auto` does, but, in most cases, it can be automatically substituted via a regex-with-captures search.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a feature for a refactoring plug-in for Eclipse CDT (I actually proposed such to my students some time ago). May be next term I can find a team to create such. However, Eclipse CDT's information might not be good enough to always determine the right stuff.

For some initilizer lists, e.g., those filling a vector, boost::assign could be a replacement. Our Mockator mock-object infrastructure uses these for C++03 instead of initializer lists in C++11.

You shouldn't be afraid of Boost libraries, at least not of those that come as header-only. Those that have separate libary parts can be a slight hassle to set up correctly (build situation improved lately).