# Automate backporting c++11 auto declarations

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

I have a C++11 codebase that I need to build with a pre-11 toolchain. Most of the 11 features used have boost equivalents so that's not too much of a problem. But there are a large number of 'auto' declarations.
Is there a good method of preprocessing the source to replace all the auto declarations with the explicit type? Perhaps redefine auto as MYUNKNOWNTYPE, then run each file through the compiler and parse the "cannot convert the_type_i_actually_wanted to MYUNKNOWNTYPE", or maybe there's some trace/diag option in the 11 version of gcc/clang that will dump them all out?

Comment: May be implemented with clang tooling/rewrite: from the AST, you may get the type of the expression...

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935590/replace-auto-keyword-with-deduced-type-clang-or-vs2010?rq=1

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but you might be able to use BOOST_AUTO with a bit of preparsing of your source.