# Is it possible to replace "auto" with its deduced type, automatically, in C++?

Tags: c++, types, refactoring, auto, automated-refactoring

I've got a project I've been wrestling with for a while, which is almost ready for submission; but there have been a few previous coders who have contributed. Their code is great, but it doesn't satisfy the lint for the project this class is going to be submitted to; so, I'm spending some time cleaning it up.

One of the things this project forbids is the `auto` keyword. This is understandable, as a lot of people contribute to it, and they aren't all the most experienced so much as enthusiastic; so being explicit is a good thing.

There are quite a few `auto`s in here. I remember that `g++ -E` would give me a file after the preprocessor was run, and it occurs to me that there's probably a way to do something similar with type specifiers.

Failing that, I'm using Qt Creator on a Linux box, which might also have a feature (kind of like "replace symbol under cursor") which I don't know about yet.

Is there anything that will allow me to automatically replace `auto` with its deduced type name, in a C++ file?

Comment: Not possible in general. E.g., `auto lambda = [&](args...) { return result; }` you cannot replace the `auto` with anything more explicit. There may be a tool for other instances where it is possible though (probably some clang-tidy fix?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace auto keyword with deduced type (clang or VS2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935590/replace-auto-keyword-with-deduced-type-clang-or-vs2010)

Comment: Oh Lord... I understand the idea of auto, but I can't help but feel like, once upon a time, there may have been a less haphazard and more modular way to implement that feature.

I don't suppose there are any tools that could help me with non-lambda and more explicit cases? Some of these types are pretty buried.

In any case, thank you guys for the prompt response!

Comment: @MichaelMacha its maybe less automated than you would hope, but VS Code has the ability to display the type of auto declared variables just by mousing over them, and its pretty good at finding the type if your workspace and includes are reasonable. Sometimes it fails and reports <error-type> but if you only have a few instances, that may be a reasonable way to replace them, having done it myself before for small sections of projects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible in general, for multiple reasons.

Firstly, there are cases where `auto` refers to unnamed types, such as closure types of lambdas, etc.

```cpp
struct {
    int data;
} stuff;

auto s = stuff{}; // What exactly is auto here, decltype(stuff) ?

auto l = []{}; // What exactly is auto here?
               // decltype([]{}) is not the same type,
               // and the closure type has no name.
               // ... should we auto-generate a typedef?
```

But even if you always had a usable type, how exactly should it be formatted?

```cpp
// What exactly is auto here?
//  - std::uint8_t
//  - ::std::uint8_t
//  - uint8_t
//  - unsigned char
//  - unsigned __char
auto c = get_uint8();

// What exactly is auto here?
//  - std::string
//  - std::basic_string<char>
//  - std::basic_string<char, std::allocator<char>>
//  - std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::__cxx11::allocator<char>>
auto str = get_std_string();
```

Knowing which type to display to the user is an extremely difficult problem in C++. IDEs often have special cases to deal with this. For example, CLion may display `std::basic_string<char>` as `string`, but this is not an automated transformation.

Comment: And then there are trailing return types.  And uses where the inferred type is dependent on template arguments.